# Discord.JS - How do i see if message.content is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i am creating a Discord user verification bot that generates a 2048 bit key when you join a server, it will be used for verification if your account gets hacked or stolen so you can know the new account is the previous person.

I have got the Key Generation down but i am having a problem with seeing if `message.content` is in some array

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
var array = fs.readFileSync('./keys.txt').toString().split("\n");
})
```

I am converting a text file to an array, but then i am stumped.
The bot is suppose to check all messages for the key, if found it will tell all users that the new user is verified to be the old user in a channel.
Can someone please tell me how to check if a message comes from an array? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "check if a message comes from an array?"? If the message the user sent is a value of an array?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. I was trying to run a check every message to see if what they said was in the array i set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to check if the message sent is one of the key you stored in your file `keys.txt`.
Then the following should do the trick :

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  var array = fs.readFileSync('./keys.txt').toString().split("\n");

  if (array.includes(message.content)) {
    message.channel.send('User verified, let's proceed...');
  } else {
    message.channel.send('User not recognized');
  }
});
```

`.includes()` checks if an element exists in the array. Check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for this! 
Works exactly as intended, i had to fix up your code a bit though.
`client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    var array = fs.readFileSync('./keys.txt').toString().split("\n");
  
    if (array.includes(message.content)) {
      message.channel.send('User verified, lets proceed...');
    } else {
      message.channel.send('User not recognized');
    }
  });`

Comment: @CollierPlays I didn't put it since it is not related to the question but you're right, always make sure you don't create a loop with your bot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript function:

```
Array.isArray(message.content);
```

It will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it seems that i cant pull from the array i made before:
   `var array = fs.readFileSync('./keys.txt').toString().split("\n");`
I am trying to grab all keys, lets say 1 from that file and check if message.content has 1
If the message includes "1" message another channel that he is verified to be his old user